# Anyone have experience integrating with MYOB?

Tags: php, sql-server, oledb, accounting, myob

Looking to integrate a web application with MYOB. There's not much in terms of documentation out there. I've found a couple of companies that provide middleware, but nothing promising. Just thought I'd see if anyone else out there has had experience with this and might be able to save me a bit of time.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you want to do with the myob database.
Retrieve information is fairly easy, there is a [myob odbc connector](http://myob.com/servlet/Satellite?cid=1131944311941&pagename=MYOB%2FPage%2FPersonalisedContentPageWithNav&site=en_AU&c=Page)  you can install.

Write permission requires you to be a myob developer partner, costs you a lot more per year.

I did a job to synchronize data from MYOB db to MySql.  So all the updates in myob db is reflected in mysql, but not the other way around

Answer (score 0):

You may want to wait...

MYOB is overhauling their **90's style application** (netbios/etc), moving it to .net framework with an API (they said it would be done Q2 2009, moved to Q2 2010).

They have non complaint SQL syntax (insert/select), **yes that's right only two keywords...** (the idea is if you screw up the query, say to an invoice, you have to write a insert into the credit table)

Unfortunately, read/write functionality doesn't come with the MYOB licence. If I can remember correctly it was Read for **AUD$250** one time and **AUD$800yr** for write permissions. Most companies can afford as it cuts down on labor.

The ODBC driver hard to use, because it executes the MYOB application and leaves it in the background. (you may want to create your own rest service to query)